# How to refresh a particular DIV upon data change in the DATABASE but without reloading the whole page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, reload

In the below code you can see a DIV class="inprg" shows up messages and a couple of buttons on the screen upon the value of database field  'trans_status = ' but user requires to reload the page. How can I make it auto?

```
<?php
        
        $where="where qu_id={$b_info['qid']} and (trans_status = 'Completed')  ";
        $order_list=$obj->get_all_records("manage_order",$where,"order_id","DESC");
        if(($_SESSION['u_id']==$buyeridaaa || ($_SESSION['u_id']==$s_id)) && !empty($r))
        {
            $token=$order_list[0]['token'];
            $release_flag=$order_list[0]['release_flag'];
            $ord_dispute=$order_list[0]['dispute'];
            echo '<div class="toolbar"><div class="in_progr">';
            if($release_flag=='N' && $ord_dispute=='N')
            {   
                $inprog='<div id="order_status1" class="inprg" style="color:#81CC40">Deposited: '.$order_list[0]['order_amt'] .'&#8381;</div>';
                if($_SESSION['u_id']==$buyeridaaa)
                {
                    echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="tkn" value="'.$token.'">';
                    echo $dispute_b.'<button type="submit" class="release_btn" name="submit_release" value="1">Release</button>
                    </form>'.$inprog;
                }
                else if($_SESSION['u_id']==$s_id)
                {
                    echo $inprog;
                }
            }
            else if ($ord_dispute=='Y') {
                
                echo '<div id="order_status2" class="inprg" style="color:red">Deal disputed!</div>';
            
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div id="order_status3" class="inprg" style="color:orange">No Deposit!</div>';
            }
            
            
            echo '</div></div>';
        }
        
        ?>
```

Comment: You've already mentioned one way of doing it in your tags... use Ajax. Have you made any attempt using it?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried to refresh the DIV periodically but didn't get results.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried and explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: jquery attempt I cleared because it became a mess. Now I have shown the original code in my post and somehow tried to explain my requirements. Could we please start from this point?

Comment: That's not how this site works though. We're here to help you sort out issues with your existing code, not to write it all for you (which we would need to do in this case since there's no attempt at all included). We don't take requirements and just hand over code. We need to see some effort. This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Have a look what I tried '<script>
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#order_status1").load("bidding-form.php");
         $("#order_status2").load("bidding-form.php");
         $("#order_status3").load("bidding-form.php");
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#order_status1").load("bidding-form.php");
            $("#order_status2").load("bidding-form.php");
            $("#order_status3").load("bidding-form.php");
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>'

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called websockets: https://www.google.com/search?q=websockets

Websockets allow your frontend to hook up to your backend and allow your backend to sent messages to frontend on which the frontend can react.

There are multiple libraries and services available to help you establish this. I suggest you first study the technology and available tools.